# Joining a table inside a split statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, delimiter

after splitting a comma delimited string into columns I'd like to combine the result with two other columns from another table.

```
     SELECT A.ID,  
 Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY 
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT ID,
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY  
     FROM  JOA_COMPANY_DEMO A 
     WHERE SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY != '' 

 ) AS A CROSS APPLY SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

This is the code i have for joining the tables

```
 Select B.Code, B.Description FROM vBo B
 INNER JOIN JOA_COMPANY_DEMO A
 ON A.SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY=B.Code 
 WHERE B.TableName = 'SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY'
```

This is what i have

```
ID      SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY
0520xxx 0001
0520xxx 0002
0520xxx 0003
```

This is what im trying to get with the supplier matching the code

```
   ID      SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY  Code Description
    0520xxx 00016              00016    Clocks
    0520xxx 00016              00016    Clocks
    0520xxx 00003              00003    soose
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu use a derived table:

```
 Select B.Code, B.Description 
 FROM vBo B
 INNER JOIN (
         SELECT A.ID,  
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY 
         FROM  
         (
             SELECT ID,
                 CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY  
             FROM  JOA_COMPANY_DEMO A 
             WHERE SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY != '' 

         ) AS A CROSS APPLY SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
 ) A
 ON A.SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY=B.Code 
 WHERE B.TableName = 'SUPPLIER_SPECIALTY'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but i still get only two columns instead of the desired 4. Code and Description whereas id like to get 
ID SUPPLIER CODE DESCRIPTION

Comment: Then add those fields, I have no idea what table they come from.